# Problem loading Pytorch Tacotron2 model with only the pth file

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, text-to-speech

I've trained a Tacotron2 model, using Mozilla TTS, on a custom dataset. The trainer outputs a pth file and a config.json file. I have difficulty loading the trained model into PyTorch.

```
from torchaudio.models.tacotron2 import Tacotron2
tacotron2 =Tacotron2()
tacotron2.load_state_dict(torch.load('models/best_model.pth'))
```

> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Tacotron2:   Missing
> key(s) in state_dict: "embedding.weight",
> "encoder.convolutions.0.0.weight", "encoder.convolutions.0.0.bias",
> "encoder.convolutions.0.1.weight", "encoder.convolutions.0.1.bias",
> "encoder.convolutions.0.1.running_mean",
> "encoder.convolutions.0.1.running_var",
> "encoder.convolutions.1.0.weight", "encoder.convolutions.1.0.bias",
> "encoder.convolutions.1.1.weight", "encoder.convolutions.1.1.bias",
> "encoder.convolutions.1.1.running_mean",
> "encoder.convolutions.1.1.running_var",
> "encoder.convolutions.2.0.weight", "encoder.convolutions.2.0.bias",
> "encoder.convolutions.2.1.weight", "encoder.convolutions.2.1.bias",
> "encoder.convolutions.2.1.running_mean",
> "encoder.convolutions.2.1.running_var", "encoder.lstm.weight_ih_l0",
> "encoder.lstm.weight_hh_l0", "encoder.lstm.bias_ih_l0",
> "encoder.lstm.bias_hh_l0", "encoder.lstm.weight_ih_l0_reverse",
> "encoder.lstm.weight_hh_l0_reverse",
> "encoder.lstm.bias_ih_l0_reverse", "encoder.lstm.bias_hh_l0_reverse",
> "decoder.prenet.layers.0.weight", "decoder.prenet.layers.1.weight",
> "decoder.attention_rnn.weight_ih", "decoder.attention_rnn.weight_hh",
> "decoder.attention_rnn.bias_ih", "decoder.attention_rnn.bias_hh",
> "decoder.attention_layer.query_layer.weight",
> "decoder.attention_layer.memory_layer.weight",
> "decoder.attention_layer.v.weight",
> "decoder.attention_layer.location_layer.location_conv.weight",
> "decoder.attention_layer.location_layer.location_dense.weight",
> "decoder.decoder_rnn.weight_ih", "decoder.decoder_rnn.weight_hh",
> "decoder.decoder_rnn.bias_ih", "decoder.decoder_rnn.bias_hh",
> "decoder.linear_projection.weight", "decoder.linear_projection.bias",
> "decoder.gate_layer.weight", "decoder.gate_layer.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.0.0.weight", "postnet.convolutions.0.0.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.0.1.weight", "postnet.convolutions.0.1.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.0.1.running_mean",
> "postnet.convolutions.0.1.running_var",
> "postnet.convolutions.1.0.weight", "postnet.convolutions.1.0.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.1.1.weight", "postnet.convolutions.1.1.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.1.1.running_mean",
> "postnet.convolutions.1.1.running_var",
> "postnet.convolutions.2.0.weight", "postnet.convolutions.2.0.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.2.1.weight", "postnet.convolutions.2.1.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.2.1.running_mean",
> "postnet.convolutions.2.1.running_var",
> "postnet.convolutions.3.0.weight", "postnet.convolutions.3.0.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.3.1.weight", "postnet.convolutions.3.1.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.3.1.running_mean",
> "postnet.convolutions.3.1.running_var",
> "postnet.convolutions.4.0.weight", "postnet.convolutions.4.0.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.4.1.weight", "postnet.convolutions.4.1.bias",
> "postnet.convolutions.4.1.running_mean",
> "postnet.convolutions.4.1.running_var".   Unexpected key(s) in
> state_dict: "config", "model", "optimizer", "scaler", "step", "epoch",
> "date", "model_loss".

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, what the `load_state_dict()` command was expecting was apparently a dictionary with keys being named network parameters like *"decoder.attention_rnn.bias_hh"* etc, i.e. the trained parameters and a way to identify them.
It seems however that the `pth` checkpoint is a binarized python dictionary, containing all of the necessary ingredients to resume training (rather than just employ the model). I'm guessing that:

- *"config"* are the arguments passed to the model during construction
- *"model"* the trained weights
- *"optimizer"* the optimizer state
- *"scaler"* no idea
- *"step"* the trainng step,
- *"epoch"* the training epoch,
- *"date"* self explanatory and
- *"model_loss"* ditto.

Try perhaps

```
checkpoint = torch.load('models/best_model.pth')
tacotron2.load_state_dict(checkpoint["model"])
```

and see what happens. If it doesn't work, check the keys of the nested dictionary `checkpoint["model"]` and explore around.

If you passed any non-default arguments during training, you'll need to replicate them (hint: use the config) when initializing for loading too.